# Probability of the messages

Tags: probability

There is a communication line between A and B. A send k messages k times(where k>1 and all messages are the same). If this message received from B, B sends t(t>1 acknowledgment to A). Message and acknowledgment arrives its destination probability is 0.80.

a)what is the probability of the both k and t received each other?

b)what is the probability of k received from B ,but t does not received from A.

c)what is the probability of t does not received from A ,but k does received from A.

d)what is the probability of both t and k did not received anyone.

My solutions for the question below;

a)P(A∩B) = P(A)xP(B|A)

0.8x0.8= 0.64

b)P(B|A)= 0.8

c) 0

d) 1-0.64 = 0.36

Am i doing correct?

Comment: This problem might be more complicated than it seems if you don't know which $t$ confirms which $k$. Do you send a bunch of messages together and just receive some number of confirmations without reference?

Comment: t is just confirm that received one of the k. which of the k not important all of them the same. I can send n times of messages ,but not the same time.

Comment: The problems says you send $k$ messages $k$ times. I'm not sure of what's the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sense that English is not your 1st language. Let me rephrase your question.
I think you mean to ask:

A transmits a message k times to B.

If B receives at least one message, B sends an ack t times.

The probability of successful transmission of any message in either direction is 0.8.

In your approach you are thinking on the right lines, but you are only using the probabilities for one message. So for t=k=1 you're ok.

For any k>=1, the probability of at least one message getting through is 1 minus the probability of no messages getting through. Assuming that successes are independent, this is simply: $$1-(1-0.8)^k$$

Apply this rule to t as well and you will solve it. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you. Yes Englis is not mine first language. I only thought about k=1, now i understand!